# Browsers reported SSL error when one of the server {..} blocks in NGINX configuration was removed

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

After deleting a `server {..}` block from NGINX configuration and keeping two other `server {..}` block strange SSL errors starting showing up on the browsers:

- Chrome reported the error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
- Firefox reported SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_NEW_SESSION_TICKET
- Curl reported gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received

For some strange reason, these browser errors took place after removing one of the `server {..}` blocks and restarting NGINX. Running `nginx -t` before the restart showed a valid NGINX configuration with no problems. However, the restart introduced these problems.

I'm using Let's Encrypt certificates.

```
nginx -V

OUTPUT:
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nchan --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module --add-module=/build/nginx-1.14.0/debian/modules/passenger/src/nginx_module
```

Answer (score 2):

After investigating this for so much time, the only thing that solved it was:

1. Moving all the `ssl_session_tickets off;` outside the `server {...}` blocks in NGINX
2. Add a single line inside the `http {..}` block of nginx with:

```
http {
...
    ssl_session_tickets off;
...
}
```

The answer [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/errors-from-browsers-with-ssl-session-tickets-off-nginx/18124/4) helped alot:

> ssl_session_tokens off breaks if it’s not set the same for all
> ssl-enabled server{} blocks. So if you have 2 server configurations
> and and you have ssl_server_tokens set to on in one (which is the
> default so it counts even if you omit it) and set to off in another,
> it will break the one where it’s set to off in certain browsers. The
> easiest way to resolve this, unless you have multiple http{} blocks,
> is to just set it to off in the http{} block. I have not tested to see
> if you you can have different settings in different http{} blocks as I
> haven’t had need to set up more than one http{} block.

Although it might not be the exact same case, but the suggestion for moving `ssl_session_tickets off;` to the `http {..}` block and remove them from all `server {..}` blocks fixed the problem for me.